# jQuery: How can i put on each a href link iframe will opened in center of page with center aligment?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found a way to solve this issue about closing iframe element by using jQuery. But it has opened 2 more issues. How can I use a href link opens an iframe object center of page of this way to replace all menu items. And when I close the content in iframe windows all element does recovery in back state?!

I post sample video which to see the theme of site I want iframe to stay in the same page like transparency defined in css as rule. I have some ideas to put on every link on menu iframe with different page conents and at bottom to paste some button for close. I hope someone has ideas to write. I'd be thankful!

Video: [here!](https://youtu.be/ZdaOWqEHHfU)

jQuery code:

```
     $('document').ready(function(myFunc){
        'use strict';
        var htmlString;
        var oldState = $('#main-page').clone();

        $('iframe').addClass('.decoration');

      $('#aboutWin').click( function(e){
            event.preventDefault();
            htmlString = $(this).html('<iframe src="./content/about.html"/>');
            $('#main-page').replacewith(htmlString);
        });

        $("#btncls").on('click', function(){
            /*var iframes = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
            for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
                iframes[i].parentNode.removeChild(iframes[i]);
            }*/
            $('html').detach();

            $('#main-page').append(oldState);
            if($('#btncls').onclick()){
               return myFunc;
            };
    });

});
```

PageCode here:

```
<body>
    <div id=main-page class="decoration">
        <div id="cover-gif">
    <div id="center">
       <ul class="main-menu">
           <li><a id="index.html" class="fontEuroStreet cool-link">Home</a></li>
           <li><a id="storiesWin" class="fontEuroStreet cool-link">Stories</a></li>
           <li><a id="scriptsWin" class="fontEuroStreet cool-link">Scripts</a></li>
           <li><a id="downloadsWin" class="fontEuroStreet cool-link">Downloads</a></li>
           <li><a id="aboutWin" class="fontEuroStreet cool-link">About</a></li>
        </ul> 
    </div>
    <div id=short-content>
        <h1 class="head-text fontPolyReg">Welcome to Polyveil site!</h1>
        <p class="short-text fontEuroRoad">Hello! In this site will be sharing mysterious things about universe, new age technologies, using SCM/CLEO scripting in GTA Vice City.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I re-post here code from about.html:

```
<cc>
<body style="width: 320px; height: 240px;" class="decoration">
    <img src="../_main_src/info.png" style="clear both; float: left; margin-left: 24px;" />
    <h1 class="head-text fontXoloB" style="float: center; padding-top: 16px; padding-left: 86px;">About</h1>
    <div class="h-line" style="margin-left: 32px; padding-left: 2px;">
        <iframe src="../content/about%20mission.txt" class="decoration infoblock fontXoloReg" style="text-align: left; float: left; margin-left: 4px; position: relative; color: mediumaquamarine;"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="h-line" style="margin-top: 482px; margin-left: 32px;"><input id="btncls" type="button" value="Close" class="button cool-link fontXoloB" /></div>
</cc>
```

Comment: Where is `#btncls`? Where is `myFunc` defined? You are aware that `$('html').remove();` removes every thing (if it actually works, not tested just theory) so the next line: `$('#main-page').append(oldState);` wouldn't because  `$('#main-page')` has been removed like everything else, plus it wouldn't be there if the about link was clicked: `$('#main-page').replacewith(htmlString);`

Comment: Hello, sir. yes i forget to post code of about.html which is external document my idea of any a href link to do post shotcut to external pages. Basicaly the theme which i planed it's to open in same window centered.